# Quartz Cluster recovery mechanism

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I run a simple controller with spring to test quartz capabilities.

```
@PostMapping(path = ["/api/v1/start/{jobKey}/{jobGroup}"])
fun start(@PathVariable jobKey: String, @PathVariable jobGroup: String): ResponseEntity<String> {

    val simpleJob = JobBuilder
        .newJob(SampleJob::class.java)
        .requestRecovery(true)
        .withIdentity(JobKey.jobKey(jobKey, jobGroup))
        .build()

    val sampleTrigger = TriggerBuilder
        .newTrigger()
        .withIdentity(jobKey, jobGroup)
        .withSchedule(
            SimpleScheduleBuilder
                .repeatSecondlyForever(5)
                .withMisfireHandlingInstructionIgnoreMisfires())
        .build()

    val scheduler = factory.scheduler

    scheduler.jobGroupNames.contains(jobGroup)
    if (scheduler.jobGroupNames.contains(jobGroup)) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Scheduler exists.")
    }

    scheduler.scheduleJob(simpleJob, sampleTrigger)
    scheduler.start()

    return ResponseEntity.ok("Scheduler started.")
}

@PostMapping(path = ["/api/v1/stop/{jobKey}/{jobGroup}"])
fun stop(@PathVariable jobKey: String, @PathVariable jobGroup: String): String {

    val scheduler = factory.scheduler
    scheduler.interrupt(JobKey.jobKey(jobKey, jobGroup))

    val jobGroupNames = scheduler.jobGroupNames
    logger.info("Existing jobGroup names: {}", jobGroupNames)

    return scheduler.deleteJob(JobKey.jobKey(jobKey, jobGroup)).toString()
}
```

Then I start two applications on different ports with the same code and start playing with it. Let's call them APP1 and APP2
I use PostgreSQL as JobStore.

So I run several scenarios.

1) Create the job with group1 and key1 in APP1

2) Try to create a job with group1 and key1 in APP2. - it gives the error that the job already started. The behavior is like I expected.

3) Stop APP1. I expect that the job will be executed in APP2, as it still exists in JobStore, but it didn't. Do I need to provide some additional configuration?

4) Start APP1, also nothing happens. Furthermore, the record for group1 and key1 still presented in DB and can't be started.

Do I need to modify shutdown behavior to remove job on the application shutdown and start jobs in another application? or I just need to configure the trigger in some another correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, that was a silly problem. I forget to start sheduler in my application

```
@Bean
open fun schedulerFactory(): SchedulerFactory {
    val factory = StdSchedulerFactory()
    factory.initialize(ClassPathResource("quartz.properties").inputStream)
    factory.scheduler.start() // this line was missed
    return factory
}
```